# Is there a known issue with @icloud.com users not being able to add files to a shared Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, icloud

We have shared a Google Drive with a couple of users with a @icloud.com email address, and they are not able to drag files into the folder that was shared. They had 'Editor' permissions which should've allowed this.

Other users have been able to do this with other email addresses. Is there something that I'm missing in regards to how icloud.com and Google Drive work with each other?

This is not a team drive, but a My Drive. This is also with GSuite.

Comment: GoogleDrive is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: I at least appreciate the response @DavidPostill